# Twig string render and Symfony extensions

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using twig in my Symfony2 project to render templates form variable:

```
$env = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$render = $env->render(
    $renderString,
    $params
);
```

But when I trying to use Symfony twig functions(such as 'path', 'url', 'asset', 'controller', etc) it throws exception "The function "path" does not exist in...".
There is the way to inject this function to the Twig_Environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
$twig = clone $this->get('twig');
$twig->setLoader(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$rendered = $twig->render(
    "Test string template: {{ result|humanize }}",
    array("result" => "mega_success")
);
```

cf. [How to render a string as a Twig template in Symfony2](https://www.techpunch.co.uk/development/render-string-twig-template-symfony2)

Comment: I wonder if there are any gotchas when cloning the original twig environment (like potential memory problems or strange side effects in the original environment)?

Answer (score 12):

This method works without cloning the twig environment: (Tested in symfony 3)

```
$rendered = $this->get('twig')
    ->createTemplate('Hi {{ name }}!')
    ->render(['name' => 'simon']);
```

Symfony extensions like `path` work, like requested.

Comment: This is a cleaner solution as it doesn't require instantiating additional objects and "twig" service can be injected inside your service. Though, sadly, there is no interface for Twig_Environment class.